# Qt Creator: “inline function used but never defined” – why?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Why am I getting this warning in Qt Creator:  ` inline function ‘bool Lion::growl ()’ used but never defined?

I double-checked my code, and have a declaration

`inline bool growl ()` in `Lion` (`lion.h`)

and the corresponding implementation in `lion.cpp`:

`inline bool Lion::growl ()`

What’s going on?

EDIT: My assumption has been that it is legal to define the actual inline method in the .cpp file (the `inline` keyword alerts the compiler to look for the method body elsewhere), or am I mistaken?

I don't want to clutter my header files with implementation details.

Comment: side note: What i have learned that inline functions are implemented in the header file (or in a seperate inl file that is include at the bottom of a header).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Well, I don't know the exact problem, but for starters:

- Inline methods are supposed to be implemented in the header file. The compiler needs to know the code to actually *inline* it.
- Also using the "inline" keyword in the class declaration doesn't have any effect. But it cannot hurt either.

See also: [c++ faq lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html)

Comment: Personally (and this is a matter of taste), I *hate* code that explicitly marks code as inline - either with the inline keyword, or by putting the implementation in the header file for 2 reasons: 1) it breaks encapsulation. 2) it hurts performance - yes, you heard me. Who do you think knows whether inlining a mathod will result in a performance boost best: the compiler, or the programmer. Seriously people, trust your optimisers, they do a better job (in many cases, but not all) then you ever will.

Comment: @Thomi if I'm just creating a 1-line wrapper around a function, I'm pretty sure it is better for it to be inlined.

Comment: Microsoft is saying that they can get a big performance increase in link times and size reduction in static libs by enforcing this rule: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/09/26/feedback-making-zc-inline-default-for-debug-release-configs-in-14.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> Inline methods are supposed to be implemented in the header file. The
>   compiler needs to know the code to actually inline it.

Except if the inline function is used in the same project, possibly in another file that *#include* its header.

I miss there is such a restriction for libraries because restricting headers to function prototypes make things more readable.

What about *#include*-ing the .cpp ?

Comment: C++ requires "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used." _n3337 basic.def.odr /3_ That essentially means that when an inline function  is declared in a header it should also be defined in the header.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Johan said, you cannot have a separate definition and declaration for the function even if both are in the same header file. This holds true especially for member functions of classes. The function code should be of the form:

```
class someClass
{
void someFunc()
{ ... }
}
// This will make the function inline even w/o the explicit 'inline'
```

***And NOT of the form***

```
class someClass
{
public:
     void someFunc();
}

void someClass::someFunc()
{ ... }
```

Comment: You actually can have a separate definition and declaration: `class C { inline void f(); }; void C::f() {}`. You just have to use explicit `inline` rather than implicit .